# ¿Debería poner todos los telefonos de un cliente como atributos en una base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Sucede que el cliente tiene teléfono de casa, teléfono de oficina y celular. ¿Hay algún problema en que todos sean atributos de la entidad cliente? o ¿debería hacer una tabla diferente para poner todos los teléfonos?

Comment: De hecho(en lo personal) lo considero bastante válida... Al agregar 3 atributos a la tabla, como limitarías si algún cliente posee alguno(o ninguno en caso extremo) campo vacío?? Lo conveniente para evitar este tipo de campos creados con valores nulos, sería tener otra tabla en la que solo se almacene los números y mediante la clave foránea ir relacionando... Y si no tiene número simplemente no se inserta nada. Con respecto al tipo de teléfono, para eso está el enum.

Comment: No hay ningún problema, si esos son los únicos datos a considerar no te conviene complicar el diseño de las tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Habéis olvidado el principio básico de las bases de datos relacionales "M-M" 
Muchos usuarios pueden tener muchos teléfonos, por tanto los teléfonos estarán en una tabla aparte y otra tabla para relacionar a los usuarios con los "x" teléfonos que tendrán:

```
Tabla Usuarios:     Tabla relación:            Tabla telefono
dni---usuario        idUsuario---idTelef       numTelf
1A....Edu            1A.... 123                 123 
2B.... Ali           1A.... 456                 456
                     2B.... 789                 789

PK usuarios -> dni
PK relacion -> ambos campos
PK telef    -> numTelf
```

Finalmente la tabla relación tendrá que tener las foreing Key a su tabla de usuario y a teléfono para que sólo te deje insertar datos si existen esos datos en las correspondientes tablas.

Como ves, yo tengo 2 números de teléfono.
De esto modo conseguirás que varios usuarios puedan tener varios números de teléfono.

Comment: Correcto, pero una opción más sencilla sería tener sólo la tabla de teléfonos con `idUsuario` - `numTelef`, sin necesidad de una tabla relación intermedia.

Comment: Si claro, pero tu aplicación nunca será escalable, por un lado, los modelos de datos tienen diferentes niveles que cumplir, por ejemplo en tu caso, no pasaría del primero, aquí te dejo un enlace -> https://prezi.com/sa1uvye3hx1u/normalizacion-de-base-de-datos-nivel-1-1fn/ 
 aparte si la base de datos "va cambiando" según se avanza el proyecto, llegará el día que por no estar bien hecha desde 0 habrá un gran dolor de cabeza.

Comment: @EduBw en que te basas que no será escalable, a que te refieres con escalable si quiera? Es más, en este caso ni si quiera se requiere una tabla externa si solo son 3 datos puntuales.

Comment: ¿No se supone que muchos a muchos haría que, en este caso, un usuario puede poseer muchos telefonos así como un teléfono puede ser poseido por muchos usuarios?

Comment: En mi cruceta 4 personas compartimos el mismo número/extensión para ser atendidos, depende de como quieras enfocarlo. por eso al principio dije que había que hacer un modelo relacional ....

Answer (score -1):

Estaria mal, no es una buena practica, vas a tener muchos usuarios con agujeros en este caso.

podrías hacer una tabla de hechos llamada Telefono_usuario con el id del usuario, un numero y esto

una tabla llamada telefonos que sea algo asi

Tipo_Telefono
ID| Tipo

1 | Celular

2 | Telefono_Fijo

3 | Oficina

Entonces Podrias poner muchos telefonos en la tabla de hechos que hagan referencia a una persona en particular

ID | persona

2  | Eduardo

Telefono usuario

> ID_Persona | Numero  | ID_tipoTelefono
>
> 1          | 46618196|2